# API VK и ASP.NET MVC (виджет комментарии)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vkontakte-api

Ради интереса добавил виджет комментарии. При построении ,там где должен быть блок с комментариями выдает ошибку:

> Please specify correct base domain name in app settings, or use widget
>   only in localhost/*

Это можно как-то исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитать сообщение об ошибке и сделать то, что в нем написано - нужно или задать домен в настройках приложения, или использовать виджет на локальной машине - и заходить на сайт через http://localhost/.

Comment: вы направили меня в нужном направлении) Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth -Version 4.3.4.13329